# Backbone.js serializing the models attributes for syncing

Tags: php, javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to save a fairly complex model including embedded collections back to a relational database. Due to the embedded collections The data returned to the server contains objects which is fair enough. I am however building the backbone app on top of an already existing application and have to return the values in scalar form to be able to re-use the server side code.
What is the best of going about this, I was thinking of overriding the model's toJSON function however I don't really feel like it should be. So the other alternative that I can think of is to overwrite the sync method and do it there. However even that doesn't seem right. Am I missing something or is overwriting the sync method a necessary evil?

Comment: Overwriting the models `.toJSON` method is the recommended approach.

Comment: @Raynos, would you mind adding your comment as an answer, otherwise I cannot nominate it as the one that worked for me? Thanks v. much for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To overwrite the way models are saved and loaded from the database you can overwrite two Methods.

1. `Model.toJSON` place custom serialization logic here.
2. `Model.parse` place custom de-serialization logic here.

Ideally you only have custom serialization / de-serialization logic to "optimise" the database. I.e. if you have an `Age` and `DateOfBirth` field you only store one in the database in `Model.toJSON` and calculate the other in `Model.parse`.

If you need custom serialization / de-serialization logic that is *NOT* model specific then overwrite `Backbone.Sync`.

You can also overwrite `model.Sync`. This means the model will use a specific custom `Sync` function rather then using `Backbone.Sync`

Comment: If using Marionette.js this gets complicated because the default implementation is for a Marionette view to call the model's `.toJSON()` and use the returned object to bind against a Handlebars template, so Marionette will try to bind the same object that is posted to the API, which isn't always what is desired.

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea to overwrite the sync method is exactly right. toJSON should always return JSON, if it returned something other than JSON, other programmers might find it difficult to understand your code.

Comment: If it was not returning JSON I'd agree

Comment: toJSON actually returns an object that should be serialized by `JSON.stringify`

Comment: ouch. Downvote was a bit harsh, I assumed "Scalar form" was not JSON, and took a stab at it.